# changing value of text field using keyup issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically inserting rows onto a page. What I'm trying to do is calculate all the Monday input data and show it in a total box. Numbers can be input in either whole numbers or in .25, .50, .75 increments and it will round up if you use any number in between.

I have this working when I use `blur` but I'd really like it to work on `keyup` so it updates on the fly.

My issue is that if I use `keyup`, the value will automatically change back to the value **corrected** value, unless I hold down delete. Type 2.23 for an example of this.

Without completely re-writing my code, is there a way I can have the total field update on the fly? I have been scratching my head over this most of the afternoon.  Any help is appreciated.

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.Monday', findTotalMon);

function findTotalAll() {
  var arr = document.getElementsByName('total');
  var tot = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseFloat(arr[i].value))
      tot += parseFloat(arr[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById('totalHoursAll').value = tot;
  if (tot === 0) {
    document.getElementById('totalHoursAll').value = '';
  }
}

function findTotalMon() {

  var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('Monday');

  var tot = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseFloat(arr[i].value)) {
        var newValue = '';
        newValue = (.25 * Math.round(4 * arr[i].value));
        arr[i].value = newValue;
        tot += parseFloat(newValue);
        
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('totalHoursMon').value = tot;
  if (tot === 0) {
    document.getElementById('totalHoursMon').value = '';
  }
 
  findTotalAll();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control full-width Monday" name="monday" id="monday" type="number" />
<input name="total" id="totalHoursMon" type="text" readonly/>
```

Comment: What about you wait until blur to change the value in the input but leave the rest the way it is? This way the totals will automatically update and the input will not change until you clock out of it. Another method you can use is instead of updating the input field you can add a faded text to the right of it with the updated value and leave the input field alone.

Comment: Can you show me an example of what you mean @RBCunhaDesign?

Comment: Ideally the total for that day should update as you type it.  I can switch to on blur but then the total doesn't update until the blur occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original Answer**

---

I’m on a mobile device, but I’m gonna try to explain what I meant.

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.Monday', findTotalMon);

function findTotalAll() {
  var arr = document.getElementsByName('total');
  var tot = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
if (parseFloat(arr[i].value))
  tot += parseFloat(arr[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById('totalHoursAll').value = tot;
  if (tot === 0) {
document.getElementById('totalHoursAll').value = '';
  }
}

function findTotalMon() {

  var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('Monday');

  var tot = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
if (parseFloat(arr[i].value)) {
    var newValue = '';
    newValue = (.25 * Math.round(4 * arr[i].value));

    // Don’t change this value yet
    // This is causing the input to change as you type
    /* arr[i].value = newValue; */

   // Instead you can create an html element next to the input
  // And update the element with the new value
  // After the user clicks out of the input you can then either update the input with the new value
  // Or you can leave the input the way it is and keep the updated values beside the input 



    tot += parseFloat(newValue);

}
  }

  document.getElementById('totalHoursMon').value = tot;
  if (tot === 0) {
document.getElementById('totalHoursMon').value = '';
  }

  findTotalAll();
}
```

**Edited Answer**

---

This is what I had in mind when trying to explain above.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
  // Set event listener on '.Monday' inputs
  $(document).on('keyup', '.Monday', findTotalMon);
  
  // Set event listener to add new input
  $('body').on('click', '#addMore', addInput);
  
  
  
  /**
   * Add new input
   */
  function addInput() {
    // Get array with all elements with class 'monday-group'
    var arr = $('.monday-group');
    // Get array length
    var length = arr.length;
    // Set length to the insert next number
    var inputIndex = length;
    // HTML code for the new input
    var newInput = '<div class="form-group col-md-4 monday-group">' +
                 '<input class="form-control full-width Monday d-inline-block mt-2 w-75" name="monday_' + inputIndex + '" id="monday_' + inputIndex + '" type="number" placeholder="Monday-' + inputIndex + '" />' +
                 '<span class="adjusted-' + inputIndex + ' text-muted d-inline-block ml-4"></span>' +
                '</div>';

    // Check if there are 5 fields or less
    // If there are 5 fields then hide the add more button
    if ( length >= 5 ) {
      $('#addMore').css('display', 'none');
      return false;
    }

    // Insert the new input field
    $(newInput).insertAfter(arr[length - 1]);
  }

  /**
  * Get grand total
  */
  function findTotalAll() {
    // Get array with all inputs with the class of 'row-total'
    var arr = $('.row-total');
    // Set total = 0
    var tot = 0;
    
    // Loop through array and add value to totals
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (parseFloat(arr[i].value))
        tot += parseFloat(arr[i].value);
    }
    
    // Show the totals
    $('#totalHoursAll').val(tot);
    
    // If totals = 0 then leave the totals input blank instead of 0
    if (tot === 0) {
      $('#totalHoursAll').val('');
    }
  }

  /**
  * Find totals for Monday
  */
  function findTotalMon() {
    // Get inputs with a class of 'Monday'
    var arr = $('.Monday');
    // Set totals to 0
    var tot = 0;

    // Loop through array adding the totals
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (parseFloat(arr[i].value)) {
        var newValue = '';
        // Calculate the adjusted value
        newValue = (.25 * Math.round(4 * arr[i].value));

        // This is the faded text with the adjusted value
        // Include the adjusted value and display in case it is hidden
        $('.adjusted-' + i).html(newValue).css('display', 'block');

        // Set the total value
        tot += parseFloat(newValue);
      } else {
        // Hide the adjusted value and make it blank
        $('.adjusted-' + i).html('').css('display', 'none');
      }
    }

    // Update the totals
    $('#totalHoursMon').val(tot);
    
    // If totals = 0 then leave the field blank instead of 0
    if (tot === 0) {
      $('#totalHoursMon').val('');
    }

    // Calculate Grand Totals
    findTotalAll();
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container mt-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4 monday-group">
        <input class="form-control full-width Monday d-inline-block w-75" name="monday_0" id="monday_0" type="number" placeholder="Monday-0" />
        <span class="adjusted-0 text-muted d-inline-block ml-4"></span>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control row-total" id="totalHoursMon" placeholder="Monday Totals" readonly>
      <button id="addMore" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Add More</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-8">
      <input class="form-control" name="total" id="totalHoursAll" type="text" placeholder="Grand Total" readonly/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I assume the html element should be hidden?

Comment: Yeah you can leave it hidden until they start typing or even wait until they click out of the input to show the html element.

Comment: You can also add the input dynamically. There are a lot of different ways that you can do this, but it is just whatever works best for your environment.

Comment: Yeah, the way the form is working is that there could be 5 different Monday fields so it calculates them all.  In my example I've olnly used the one.  I'll have a play around and see if I can get it working using your suggestion.  Cheers!

Comment: When I get to a computer I’ll try to post a better answer and maybe include those dynamic inputs and such.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate the help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165110/discussion-between-xoog-and-rbcunhadesign).

Comment: Appreciate the help! Thanks again.